# LTspice simulation of buck converter

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, buck

I have a 12V battery and trying to connect it to a 5V MCU. To do that I need a buck converter. I have tried simulating the circuit on LTspice but I cant seem to step-down the voltage.

Given that:
Input voltage range = 10.5V-12.2V
Maximum output current = 1mA
Switching frequency = 20kHz
Output voltage ripple = 20%

This is what I have tried so far:
[image]

And the results are shown as such:
[image]

Where green is the output voltage of the mosfet and blue is the output voltage to the load.

What is the reason that the voltage doesnt drop down to 5V? What changes should I make to the simulation so that the voltage will drop to 5V?

Comment: Jeremy, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the reason that the voltage doesn't drop down to 5V?*

You are using a p-channel MOSFET incorrectly. It has a body diode that basically shorts out the MOSFET thus always allowing current to flow to the load. This means zero regulation and no control: -

[image]

Try using an n-channel MOSFET but, you also need to fix your gate control voltage so that it operates correctly.

Then, once you have fixed that, refinements can be made.

Comment: The PMOS device is appropriate for a high side switch if source and drain are reversed. But the gate signal would need to have an ON voltage of 12 V to match the input voltage. An additional NMOS or NPN with a resistor on M1 gate-source would be better so a logic level referenced to GND would be possible.